# Find rectangles whose area increases by a factor of 20 when their length and width increases by k

Tags: geometry

Is there an easy way of knowing which rectangles have the same property?

(length+k)(width+k) = 20(length*width)

Comment: You can simply plot a 3-D graph.

Answer (score 1):

You have $(L+k)(W+k)=4LW$ or $$3LW-kL-kW=k^2$$ Now multiply by $3$ to obtain $$9LW-3kL-3kW=3k^2$$Add $k^2$ to each side so that $$4k^2=(3L-k)(3W-k)$$

Given $k$ take the factors of $4k^2$ and test whether they give $L,W$ integers (I leave you to explore what rules there might be for this to save work). This reduces the problem to a finite search.

For $k=10, 4k^2=400$ the factor $1$ would give $3W=11$, the factor $2$ gives $3W=12, W=4$ and $3L=210, L=70$ etc.